# How does this function for reading a number from input work?

Tags: c, string

How has the string been manipulated to integer and what is use of bitwise operators..this function has been used in c to take input from string of numbers

```
    "gc and ll are defined like this.. typedef long long LL; 
     #define gc getchar_unlocked()"

inline LL inp()
{
LL num = 0;
char p = gc;
while(p<33)p=gc;
while(p>33) {
    num = (num << 3)+ (num << 1)+ (p -'0');
    p = gc;
}
return num;
};
```

Comment: What is `gc`? A register which changes its content on its own? If no, your code makes no sense. In general, your code doesn't make sense without further explanation; we only can guess. Or is it hidden in a macro like `#define gc getchar()` (which would be VERY bad style)? And what is `LL`?

Comment: ya gc and ll are defined like this..
    typedef long long LL;
    #define gc getchar_unlocked(

Comment: Never, never hide function calls behind macros without `()`s. At least, do `#define gc() getchar_unlocked()` and use it as `p = gc()`, so that the very nature as a function call is obvious. Or better - as explicit is better than implicit - directly do `p = getchar_unlocked()`. Never be too lazy to type some characters more. Code readability is important if you have a look on it in 2 weeks, 2 months or 2 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather that `char p = gc` obtains a character from the `input`.

`while(p<33)p=gc;` just keeps getting input until something other than a space is entered? (space is character 32 in decimal).

Then, while the input isn't a space,

`(num << 3) + (num << 1)` is equivalent to `num * 10` (`num << 3` is equivalent to `num * 8`, `num << 1` is equivalent to `num * 2`, `num * 8 + num * 2` can be written as `num * (8+2)` which simplifies to `num * 10`).

`p - '0'` turns the input character (say '9' [char 57] for example) into the corresponding integer (eg, just 9).

If the input is "123 " then num will be equal to 123, because:

num = 0;

num = 0 * 10 + 1;  (== 1)

num = 1 * 10 + 2;  (== 12)

num = 12 * 10 + 3; (== 123)

I hope that sheds some light. It is pretty bad code, and will not behave correctly if anything other than the numbers 0-9 are entered.

Writing it like this might be better:

```
// function to read one character from the 'input'
char gc();

// I'm not sure what LL is here, could be long long?
inline LL inp()
{
    LL num = 0;
    char p = gc();

    // keep reading characters until a number is encountered
    while((p < '0') || (p > '9'))
    {
        p = gc();
    }

    // loop until a non-number is encountered
    while((p >= '0') && (p <= '9'))
    {
        // Shift the previously read digits up by one 'tens' column
        num *= 10;

        // Add in the newly read digit
        num += p -'0';

        // Read the next character
        p = gc();
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: what is use of writing inline here?
i have come across inline functions only in c++..however this code is in c..compiling successfully on gcc

Comment: inline is just an instruction to the compiler - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, and it depends on a few factors in my experience. It tells the compiler to place the function inline - that is, everywhere you write `inp();` it actually copy-pastes the code for the inp function, instead of calling it as a function. Inline is a speed/space tradeoff - inline (usually) costs you space (the machine code size) while being faster (it can be faster due to better optimisation, less parameter passing, no function call overhead, but it is a very small saving on modern systems anyway).

Comment: For example, if the `inp()` function was 10kB and you called it in 100 places in your code, if it is inlined it will take up 10kB of code space every time you call it, so 1000kB total - whereas normally there is only one copy of the function which is just called from those 100 places.

Comment: If you want an inline function this is my advice: write it in a .h file only (not c file) and use the modifiers `extern inline` (for example, `extern inline LL inp()`). GCC has complex rules for when it will and won't inline a function, that's what I have the most experience with - it varies depending on the compiler. I am not sure if it is available in standard C or not, I assume it is.

Comment: Here is a good resource on inline functions: http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html